# CakePHP 2.x custom "Authentication adapter &quot;LdapAuthorize&quot; was not found

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I'm building an application using CakePHP and trying to incorporate a custom authentication object but it does not seem to be able to find it. I get the following error when I try to log in: "Authentication adapter "LdapAuthorize" was not found". I have created the file app/Controller/Component/Auth/LdapAuthorize.php with my code for my authentication. Near the top of "AppController.php" I have

```
App::uses('LdapAuthroize', 'Controller/Component/Auth/LdapAuthorize');
```

and within the AppController class I have

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect'  => array('controller' => 'pendings', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authorize'      => array('Controller'),
            'authenticate'   => array('LdapAuthorize')
        )
    );
```

and then in my UsersController.php I have the following login function.

```
        public function login() {       

        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            if($this->Auth->login()) { 
                                // My Login stuff...
                            }
                    else
                        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'someController', 'action'=>'someAction'));         
        }
    }
```

If anyone has any idea why it can't seem to load my custom authentication object that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: @ElliotVargas Do you have a solution because the above didn't work and im having the same problem?

Comment: @DeAn I just added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19522786/2024), see if it's useful to you.

Comment: @ElliotVargas Thanks, I figured it out a few weeks ago and it was as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put my custom authentication class inside **Controller/Component/Auth**. For example, the name of my class is **CustomUserAuthenticate** and the path to the file is,

> **Controller/Component/Auth/CustomUserAuthenticate.php**.

Then in my **AppController** I added the following to the `authenticate` array,

```
class AppController extends Controller {      
    public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            /** Any other configuration like redirects can go here */
            'authenticate' => array(
                'CustomUser'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

The string in the `authenticate` array must match the name of the class except for the *Authenticate* word.

My **CustomUserAuthenticate** class extends CakePHP's **Controller/Component/Auth/BaseAuthenticate** and overrides the `authenticate` method. CakePHP's documentation states that this is not [required](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects). I haven't tried that way.

Answer (score 2):

I think your `App::uses()` is wrong so it can't find the class. Your current code:

```
App::uses('LdapAuthroize', 'Controller/Component/Auth/LdapAuthorize');
```

Is trying to find **Controller/Component/Auth/LdapAuthorize/LdapAuthroize.php**

The first parameter is the class name (you have a typo with that), the second is just the path to the directory containing the class, you don't need to add the class name again.

Try this:

```
App::uses('LdapAuthorize', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I can't believe I missed that typo but this was the 500th time writing out that line. Unfortunately I still seem to be getting the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @JonHaller Did you change the second parameter as well, to `Controller/Component/Auth`?