# cakephp: Custom Authentication Object authenticate not called

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.4

The method authenticate in a Custom Authentication Object is never called. Is this a glicth or am I missing something?

I don't get anything in the log, I'm just redirected to users/login (or the one I specified)

CakeVersion: 2.4.1

```
<?php
//My custom Auth Class
//Path: app/Controller/Component/Auth/HashAuthenticate.php
App::uses('BaseAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class HashAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
{
    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response)
    {
        //Seems to not be called
        CakeLog::write('authenticate');
        debug($this);
        die('gaah');
    }
}
```

If I add the method getUser() (or unauthenticated() ), those gets called however so at least I know that cake finds the class and so on. It just skips the authenticate-method.

The AppController looks like this

```
<?php
// AppController
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('HashAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth'); 

class AppController extends Controller {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components =    array('Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array('Hash'),
        'authorize'      => array('Controller'),
        )
    );
}
```

I found a similar question here: [CakePHP 2.x custom "Authentication adapter &quot;LdapAuthorize&quot; was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094154/cakephp-2-x-custom-authentication-adapter-quotldapauthorizequot-was-not-fou) but there the issue was typos.

Comment: Could you please also show your controllers login action? It's very like that this is where the problem is located.

Comment: You are most correct sir. I wrongfully thought that authenticate was called whenever a not-logged-in user tried to access something that needed auth. But as you say it's `$this->Auth->login()` that calls authenticate. I'll focus on `getUser()` instead

Answer (score 2):

I wrongfully thought that authenticate was called whenever an unauthenticated user tried to access something protected by Auth.

As ndm pointed out authenticate is only called when doing `$this->Auth->login()`

The thing I'm trying to accomplish here is to let users login via a link, but not in a stateless way. They shouldn't have to provide the same hash (in my case) every time, just once. Instead I'll set the state (session) in the getUser() method that gets called every time a user tries to access something protected.

So hopefully this can help anyone else that has the same issue.